# Unity 2D - access to variables of GetComponent<T> sent as param

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, types

I have this script for saving my character. I have lot of NPCs and each NPC has its own script. I want to use method `SaveCharacter` for saving every NPC. How can I send `g.GetComponent<Warrior_Movement>()` as a parameter and get access to its variables? When I use `<T>`, I can't get variables of gameobject's script. Thanks

```
void SaveCharacter(Character character, string gameObjectName)
{
    GameObject g = GameObject.Find(gameObjectName);

    character.position = new float[] { g.transform.position.x, g.transform.position.y, g.transform.position.z };
    character.selectedScheme = g.GetComponent<Warrior_Movement>().selectedScheme;
    character.currentWaypointIndex = g.GetComponent<Warrior_Movement>().currentWaypointIndex;
    character.nextWaypointIndex = g.GetComponent<Warrior_Movement>().nextWaypointIndex;
    character.loopSide = g.GetComponent<Warrior_Movement>().loopSide;
}
```

Comment: are the variables public?

Comment: Yes, of course, but i can't get it by GetComponent<T>().
I want to sent Child_Movement, Warrior_Movement, Girl_Movement as param. Every script has same variables

Comment: also, you need to clarify what you mean with "params". To send a Component as params simply do `void MyMethod(params Component[] comps)`

Comment: So you're looking for the correct level of abstraction? Make them all inherit from the same Movement abstract class which holds the variables then use it with `GetComponent<Movement>()`. Or `void MyMethod(params IMovement movementScripts)`.

Comment: I want to send new param, for examle oneParam and pass it to the `GetComponent<oneParam>` and access to variables, for example `GetComponent<oneParam>().selectedScheme`

Comment: Anybody know how do that?

Comment: So you want to be able to get selectedScheme, currentWaypointIndex and nextWaypointIndex etc from either a Child_Movement, Warrior_Movement or Girl_Movement correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You can **NOT** use a variable for passing it into the generic version of `GetComponemt` like

```
public void DoSomething(Type componemtType)
{
    var component = GetComponent<componentType>();
}
```

since the types used for implementing the generics have to be **compile time constant** and therefor can not be a variable (or only one that is compile time constant)!

You could use the non-generic version of `GetComponent` like

```
public void DoSomething(Type componentType)
{
    var component = GetComponent(componentType);
}
```

**but** than you would have to parse it in order to have access to any fields or methods that are specific for that component:

```
var parsedComponent = component as componentType;
```

So again you can **NOT** do this since the type used for `as` also has to be **compile time constant** and therefor can not be a variable.

---

#### Solution 1: Shared Base class

In the case all your different classes have common fields you want to save, they should all inherit from a common base type like e.g.

```
// By making a class abstract it can not be instanced itself but only be implemented by subclasses
public abstract class BaseMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // fields that will be inherited by subclasses
    public int currentWaypointIndex;
    public int nextWaypointIndex;
    //...

    // You could also have some generic methods that are implemented
    // only in the subclasses like e.g. Getters for the values
    // you want to access
    public abstract string SaySomething();
}
```

And than inherit your classes from that like e.g.

```
public class Warrior_Movement : BaseMovement
{
    // Inherits all fields of BaseMovement

    //... additional type specific stuff

    // If you have abstract methods in the base class
    // every subclass has to implement all of them
    public override string SaySomething()
    {
        return "Harr harr, I'm a warrior!";
    }
}

public class Other_Movement : BaseMovement
{
    // Inherits all fields of BaseMovement

    // Additional type specific stuff

    // If you have abstract methods in the base class
    // every subclass has to implement all of them
    public override string SaySomething ()
    {
        return "Harr harr, I'm ... something else :'D ";
    }
}
```

Than you can use something like

```
void SaveCharacter(Character character, BaseMovent bMovement)
{
    character.position = new float[] { bMovement.transform.position.x, bMovement.transform.position.y, bMovement.transform.position.z };
    character.currentWaypointIndex = bMovement.currentWaypointIndex;
    character.nextWaypointIndex = bMovement.nextWaypointIndex;
}
```

and call it like

```
GameObject g = GameObject.Find(gameObjectName);
var movement = g.GetComponemt<BaseMovement>();

SaveCharacter(someCharacter, movement);
```

---

#### Solution 2: Overloads

Alternatively if you use different values for different components than don't use a shared base class but instead create overloads of `SaveCharacter` like

```
public void SaveCharacter(Character character, Warrior_Movement wMovement)
{
    // Do stuff with wMovement
    // ...
}

public void SaveCharacter (Character character, Other_Movement oMovement)
{
    // Do stuff with oMovement
    // ...
}
```

so the wheneever you use `SaveCharacter` the types you pass in will decide which implementation of `SaveCharacter` should be used.

---

To

> When I use , I can't get variables of gameobject's script.

I don't know what you mean exactly but you can access the `GameObject` the component is attached to by using `gameObject` e.g.

```
bMovement.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

**Note**:
If somehow possible you should avoid using `Find` since it is quite performance intense. Try to get the reference as soon as possible e.g. either by referencing it in the Inspector using a `public GameObject` field or if it is Instantiated save it to a variable like

```
var warrior = Instantiate (/*...*/);
```

and pass it around.